# How to properly select the next div with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to the select the next closest div to the input tag changed. When I run this nothing happens. I have tried the closest tag and the next tag.

```
$("input[id='declined']").change(function(){
     $(this).next('div.textarea_container').fadeIn();
});
```

Html:

```
    <div id="gcheckbox">
         <input type="radio" id="name10" class="guidelines" name="Confirmed diagnosis of melanoma" value="Accepted">
         <input type="radio" class="guidelines no_margin" name="Confirmed diagnosis of melanoma" id="declined" value="Declined">
         <label>Confirmed diagnosis of melanoma</label>
              <div class="textarea_container">
                 <textarea placeholder="reason" id="notearea0"></textarea>
              </div>
     </div>
```

I have now made a sample file. 
http://jsfiddle.net/dMmuW/

Comment: `[id='declined']` can be written `#declined` in a sizzle selector

Comment: The [doco for next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/) makes it pretty clear why it is the wrong method for that html structure...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery's [`next`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) function only works for the adjacent sibling element, use [`nextAll`](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) to get all sibling elements after the selected one and filter to the one you want.

```
$('#declined').change(function () {
    $(this).nextAll('div.textarea_container').fadeIn();
});
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. Thank you though for the suggestion.

Comment: Initial answer was written before he provided a code sample; updated now.

Comment: @KevinWeber You used the old code: use nextAll as per my updated answer. I've updated the fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/dMmuW/1/